# IIS FTP passwords encryption schema

Tags: powershell, iis, passwords, aes, rsa

This is one of my first approaches to "crypto in practice". I have found myself a new aim when I stumbled upon my password (AES encrypted) on my FTP server. Since I am eager to get to know new stuff, I decided I'll give it a go and try to 'recover' my password from AES cipher. If I can make it to decipher it 'on the paper' I think I will have a good enough understanding on how it works and how to call it.

As MSDN points out:

*The AesProvider provider is an AES provider that uses a session key encrypted using an RSA key container that has permissions for the IIS_IUSRS group, therefore allowing IIS worker processes to encrypt and decrypt configuration encrypted with this provider.*

So, the available data:

- Session key (RSA encrypted) from `<configProtectedData>`
- AES cipher from the same file (enc:AesProvider:89v45avZx.....)
- Machine RSA key (obtained using aspnet_regiis -px "SampleKeys"
  keys.xml -pri) (since useMachineContainer flag is `true`).

If I understand correctly:

In order to decrypt the password:

I need to decrypt the RSA-Encrypted session key with Machine RSA key.
Once I have the decrypted session key I use it as AES key to decrypt the password. Am I mistaken in this thinking?

If the above is correct, I will now describe my attempts:

Using Powershell (my preferable environment):

```
    [xml]$IISXML = [xml](cat .\IISConfigKey.xml)
[System.Xml.XmlElement]$IISElement = $IISXML.RSAKeyValue
$RSA = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.RSAKeyValue
    $RSA.LoadXml($IISElement)
## Now I have RSA-key loaded as an object from exported XML

    $AESSessionKey = "LIAAAZ..1aVods=" // Total length 188
## I am importing the session key from the file
$AESProviderSessionKeyBytes = (Convert-FromBase64 $AESProviderSessionKey).ToCharArray() | % { [byte]$_ }
## 'Convert-FromBase64' is my custom function, which basically converts from Base64 to String
```

And this seems to be the first culprit I can't get around. Casting `$RSA.Key.Decrypt($AESProviderSessionKeyBytes, $true)` returns an error that the data exceeded 128 bytes. Which happened in fact, as the `SessionKeyBytes` is of 140-length.

As the method I am calling happily throws exceptions at me, I have no idea what to try next. The sessionKey seems too long to be RSA-encrypted? Or maybe I should divide it? Or maybe I am just mistaken in principle that it is RSA encrypted.. I tried couple of versions, but none of them progressed me any closer.

Hope you can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Could you show us a sample `$AESProviderSessionKey`?

Comment: I think I could apparently, I can't see a risk associated with it without having machine Key or AES ciphers :-)

sessionKey="AQIAAA5mAAAApAAAQ5H8wPNjGKqVCk2ocTo8f2x2VkUhTZKY/ciy17hoEssWqT62ugnTfyPEJXxIIdP4+r5JFeBxwiCk2ljbdS4PCfxnF1FnlS+L6m6h/u42Z7Hxmi5cbLRb1K9w5WdEPYZxY6GRwdHMDiiZWkOz6iylRsMQ8QyPMeVDWUUArMGjdDQ="

Comment: As I expected, there seems to be some kind of proprietary header format before the encrypted text. Try and [convert it to hexadecimals](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php) and you'll see it's not random.

Comment: I will try to determine the header length in this case. Maybe simply stripping it off will work?

Comment: Probably. It may even be possible to just use the last 128 bytes (for a 1024 bit key).